# Counting number of sequences in a vector

Tags: r, vector, counter

I have a binary vector and I want to count how many sequences of 1's I've got. So that if I have a vector like:

```
bin <- c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1)
```

I would get `5`. I haven't found any existing functions that could do this, anyone got any good tips on how one could write one? I don't know how to build the "counter" when the sequences all have different lengths.

Comment: Ah, yes it has been asked and answered before. I'm sorry I did not find it. I guess it has to do with me not using the appropriate terms.

Comment: I found it (and many others) by searching for the title of your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The run length encoding function (`rle`) is *built* for this. Helpfully whilst it computes the length of runs of equal values in a vector, it returns those lengths *with* the values. So use `rle( bin )`.

Compare the `$values` output to your desired value (`1`) with `==` and `sum` the result (because you get a `TRUE` or `1L` when the run of values is of `1`'s):

```
sum( rle(bin)$values == 1 )
[1] 5
```